# Don't worry about YOU being alone or YOUR being alone?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, gerunds, gerund-phrases, possessive-pronouns

Can't stop wondering what the correct option is.

Or are they both correct, and the latter just sounds more formal?

Comment: I prefer: "Don't worry about being alone."

Comment: Assuming the capitals do not represent LOUD SPEECH, there's no difference. Gerunds can take possessive or objective subjects.

Comment: @JohnLawler - both correct, but I wouldn't say no difference. In one case the concern is for the person [*you* being alone] and in the other for the circumstances [your *being alone*].

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere I don't think that's a valid distinction. "I don't care about you leaving" and "I don't care about your leaving" both indicate lack of caring about the departure not about the person who is leaving.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere That may well be the way you use it (and interpret it) consistently, but individual differences are massive, and many many speakers are not aware that others have different favorite uses and interpretations of particular constructions.

Comment: @StuartF - But wouldn't the alternative to "I don't care about you leaving" be "I don't care about John leaving"? And "I don't care about your leaving" would have "I don't care about your smell"? That's how I'd use them, and reading both out loud it's where I'd put the emphasis. I'm always twitchy about "no difference" answers as they're often not universal and can indicate the speaker's priorities (sometimes subconsciously).

Comment: @JohnLawler - Absolutely. We're all just expressing opinions. The more, the merrier.